# Python cx_Oracle Insert Into table with multiple columns automating the values (1:,2: ... 100:)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, sql-insert, cx-oracle

I am working on a script to read from an oracle table with about 75 columns in one environment and load it into same table definition in a different environment. Till now I have been using cx_Oracle cur.execute() method to 'INSERT INTO TABLENAME VALUES(:1,:2,:3..:8);' and then load the data using 'cur.execute(sql, conn)' method.

However,this table that I'm trying to load has about 75+ columns and writing (:1, :2 ... :75) would be tedious and I'm guessing not part of best practice.

Is there an automated way to loop over the number of columns and automatically fill the values() portion of the SQL query.

```
user = 'username'
pass = getpass.getpass()
connection_prod = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, service_name = '')
cursor_prod = connection_prod.cursor()

connection_dev = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, service_name = '')
cursor_dev = connection_dev.cursor()

SQL_Read = """Select * from Table_name_Prod"""
Data = cur.execute(SQL_Read, connection_prod)
for row in Data:
    SQL_Load = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME_DEV VALUES(:1, :2,:3, :4 ...:75);" --This part is ugly and tedious.
    cursor_dev.execute(SQL_LOAD, row)
```

**This is where I need Help**

```
connection_Prod.commit()
cursor_Prod.close()
connection_Prod.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following which should help not only in reducing code but also in improving performance:

```
connection_prod = cx_Oracle.connect(...)
cursor_prod = connection_prod.cursor()

# set array size for source cursor to some reasonable value
# increasing this value reduces round-trips but increases memory usage
cursor_prod.arraysize = 500

connection_dev = cx_Oracle.connect(...)
cursor_dev = connection_dev.cursor()

cursor_prod.execute("select * from table_name_prod")
bind_names = ",".join(":" + str(i + 1) \
        for i in range(len(cursor_prod.description)))
sql_load = "insert into table_name_dev values (" + bind_names + ")"
while True:
    rows = cursor_prod.fetchmany()
    if not rows:
        break
    cursor_dev.executemany(sql_load, rows)
    # can call connection_dev.commit() here if you want to commit each batch
```

The use of cursor.executemany() will significantly help in terms of performance. Hope this helps you out!

Comment: The above code is giving me an error "Unexpected character after line continuation character" at the INSERT statement? Any idea what it could be for

Comment: There's a typo: `cursor.description` should be `cursor_prod.description`.  But with or without this, I don't get your error.  So it's hard to say what you have done.  Try debugging it.

Comment: I fixed the typo, I believe. If you copy/pasted from here you may have copied a hidden character unintentionally.

Comment: is there a way we can do this method where we create bind_names or checking if the column headers match with a pandas dataframe? Possibly using list comprehension like this`[tuple(x) for x in df.values]` ?

Comment: You could use names instead of positions if you wanted to do so -- but that involves building dictionaries . Unless you wanted to simply check the names and adjust the order based on the names matching? Not sure what you mean. Ask another question giving details!